# Autocomplete with adapter showing duplicate result

Tags: android

First here is my json.

```
[{"MemberId":"MI001","MemberName":"Member 1"},
{"MemberId":"MI002","MemberName":"Member 2"},
{"MemberId":"MI003","MemberName":"Member 3"}]
```

here how i put my json to my adapter

```
 @Override
 public void onResponse(JSONArray  response) {
      try {
           Model_member m_member = new Model_member();
           List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
           for(int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
                            m_member.setMember_id(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("MemberId"));
                            m_member.setMember_name(response.getJSONObject(i).getString("MemberName"));
                            Log.d("ASDF", response.getJSONObject(i).getString("MemberName"));
                            memberList.add(m_member);
                                }


                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
```

and here is my adapter.

```
public class Adapter_member extends ArrayAdapter{
    private ArrayList<Model_member> mData;
    public Adapter_member(Context context, ArrayList<Model_member> m_member) {
        super(context, 0, m_member);
        this.mData = m_member;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.single_member_layout, parent, false);
        }

        Model_member m_member = getItem(position);
        TextView memberName =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.membername);
        memberName.setText(m_member.getMember_name());
        return convertView;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Model_member getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
    }

}
```

and here is my pojo

```
public class Model_member {
    String member_id,member_name;

    public String getMember_id() {
        return member_id;
    }

    public void setMember_id(String member_id) {
        this.member_id = member_id;
    }

    public String getMember_name() {
        return member_name;
    }

    public void setMember_name(String member_name) {
        this.member_name = member_name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getMember_name().toString();
    }
}
```

So my problem is when i enter MI00 there result is like this

[image]

i only see `MI003`. the data is `looping`, i mean all of the result are `MI003`.

How can i make this working properly ? Did i miss something ?

Comment: You need to create the `Model_member` object inside the loop. Otherwise you'll just keep editing and adding the same object over and over.

Comment: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();  list.clear();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clear your previous List before inserting new items.

```
@Override
public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
    if (memberList == null) memberList = new ArrayList<>();
    memberList.clear();
```

**Reason**

> Because you have attached `memberList` to your adapter, when each time
>   response come, then you don't clear previous List, and add new items
>   again.

That is what I could find in your code.

Comment: why this answer get downvote ? this answer fix my problem